# Reallocation of memory to empty reference

Tags: c, malloc

I was watching a lesson on `malloc` and while they were doing a specific example, it made no sense for why such code to print out the entire pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    
    int *list = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    
    if (list == NULL)
        return 1;
        
    list[0] = 1;
    list[1] = 2;
    list[2] = 3;
    
    int *tmp = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    
    if (tmp == NULL)
        return 1;
        
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        tmp[i] = list[i];
        
    tmp[3] = 4;
    
    free(list);

    //From this line and below is the thing in question.
    list = tmp;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%i\n", list[i]);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
~/test/ $ ./malloc_test
1
2
3
4
```

From my understanding of `free()`, it de-allocates the memory allocated by allocation functions and `free()` will 'free' up the memory of the pointer.

If I were to go by this definition:

1. `*list` was allocated 12 bytes `(3 * sizeof(int)`,  `sizeof(int) = 4`
2. Hard code `list` with numbers
3. `*tmp` was allocated 16 bytes
4. Copy the numbers in `list` to `tmp`
5. Free up list making it have no allocated bytes
6. List is now equal to tmp

- How can `list` now be equal to `tmp` when `list` doesn't have any allocated memory?
- Is `list` pointing to the address of `tmp`? If yes, why do we need to not allocate memory for `list` since earlier in the code, we did this `int *tmp = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));`

Comment: List and tmp are references that point to the same memory address. As you have already allocated memory and assigned it to tmp, the same allocated memory can be used for List. So, malloc allocates memory which can be assigned to tmp, list or any number of pointers.

Comment: Why not use `realloc`?

Comment: You can copy pointer values just like any other value. Note that this does not copy the data.

Comment: @tadman They brought `realloc`  in the next example after this example, but I just want to know the answer to my question in regards to this example.

Comment: When they do, `list = tmp;` does it mean that `list` is pointing/referencing to `tmp`?

Comment: `malloc(4 * sizeof(int));` returns a pointer of type int and tmp holds the address of first byte in this allocated memory. When you do `list = tmp;` you are not allocating the memory again and both tmp and list hold the first byte of the already allocated memory.

Comment: @ManavDubey Just like `a = b;` sets the value of `a` to equal the value of `b`, so `list = tmp;` sets the value of `list` to the value of `tmp`.

Comment: @Akshit: *`malloc(4 * sizeof(int));` returns a pointer of type `int`* not exactly: `malloc()` returns a generic pointer that can be safely and automatically (in C) converted to a pointer to `int` when stored to `tmp`. This distinction is currently beyond the OP's skill level, but it can help understand the nature of pointers: they are simple variables that contain a memory address. Their type determines how they are dereferenced and how their value is used in an expression.

Comment: @chqrlie Agreed, I should have mentioned the casting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `*list` was allocated 12 bytes (3 * sizeof(int), sizeof(int) = 4

To be precise, you allocated 12 bytes of memory and set `list` to point to that memory.

> Hard code `list` with numbers
> `*tmp` was allocated 16 bytes

Again, to be precise, you allocated 16 bytes of memory and set the pointer variable `tmp` to point to it.

> Copy the numbers in `list` to `tmp`
> Free up `list` making it have no allocated bytes

To be precise, you freed the object that `list` pointed to so now `list` points to garbage and must not be dereferenced.

> `list` is now equal to `tmp`

To be precise, `list` now points to the same thing `tmp` points to, those 16 bytes you allocated that previous was pointed to only by `tmp`.

> How can `list` now be equal to `tmp` when list doesn't have any allocated memory?

Previously, `list` didn't point to allocated memory. But you changed it to point to the 16 bytes you allocated second. The value of a pointer is what it points to, `list` and `tmp` now point to the same thing so they have the same value. So they're now equal.

> Is list pointing to the address of tmp? If yes, why do we need to not allocate memory for list since earlier in the code, we did this int *tmp = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));

The code frees the first allocated block of memory. If it didn't allocate a second block of memory, there would be nothing valid for either pointer to point to!

Comment: Since `list` is referencing the same memory address as `tmp`, and I want to free up the memory to avoid any memory leaks, do i do `free(list)` or `free(tmp)`

Comment: @ManavDubey Those both pass the same value to `free`, so they do precisely the same thing.

Comment: @ManavDubey: you can use one or the other as they will pass the same address to `free`, but you must not do both as the second call will try and free a block that has already been freed by the first call, hence you would get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

When you copy a pointer you're just copying the pointer's value<sup>1</sup>:

```
list = tmp;
```

This means that `list` now contains a copy of the `tmp` pointer, or in other words, *they both point to the same memory address*. In this case that address is an allocation.

Once they're made identical you can reference either of them interchangeably.

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course this presumes the pointers are of the same type, like `int*` to `int*`, and not `int` to `int**`. You could also assign to `void*` and convert back again later, that works as well.

Answer (score 0):

a pointer is a data type that is only assigned memory addresses of the corresponding data type, in your case in `list = tmp;` you assign the first position of that memory block that you created with `int * tmp = malloc (4 * sizeof (int));` , when you make the assignment to list it will point to that memory address. (in your case at the beginning of that memory block).